# YAML azure piplelines & templates - Iterate through each values splitted from a string passed from main pipeline OR pass array as output with bash

Tags: bash, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm kinda stuck with this achievement i would like to have available in my build pipeline.

The main goal is to iterate through every value extracted by the function `{{split ',' parameters.PARAMETER_PASSED}}` when I'm already in the template form.

How it should looks like:

1. Build pass string that changes depending by one script `value1,value2,value3,...,valueX`
2. Template start
3. FOR EACH `valueN`, start a script with a specific displayName (in this case `${{ value}}` will be ok)

Below you can find what i've achieved so far:

`azure-pipelines.yaml`

```yaml
- stage: AutomateScriptContent
    displayName: 'Some new trick'
    jobs:
      - job: CheckFileChanges
        displayName: Prepare list
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            persistCredentials: true
          - bash: |
                #....Something..Something
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VALUE_LIST;isOutput=true;]value1,value2,value3"
              fi
            displayName: "Check"
            name: check
      - job: TestTemplate
        variables:
          LISTVAL: $[ dependencies.CheckFileChanges.outputs['check.VALUE_LIST'] ]
        displayName: "Do something with values passed from env variable"
        dependsOn: CheckFileChanges
        steps:
        - template: __templates__/test.template.yml
          parameters:
            MY_LIST: $(LISTVAL)
```

`test.template.yml`

```yaml
parameters:
  MY_LIST: ""

steps:
  - variables:
    website: {{split ',' parameters.MY_LIST}}
  # - script: echo "${{ parameters.MY_LIST }}"
  - ${{ each value in var.MY_LIST }}:
    - script: 'echo ${{ value }}'
      displayName: '${{ value }}'
```

I know that test.template.yml is not correct but I cannot understand how to make it work!

Any suggestion? Not sure if it's possible to pass from bash/powershell a new array with `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VALUE_LIST;isOutput=true;]$MY_ARRAY"

Also one accepted solution could be adding every value of the array as new parameter, output it and then pass ALL the parameters (without providing the name like below) but i'm not sure if it's possible to pass the parameters without providing each single name of each parameter (example below).

```yaml
variables:
          LISTVAL: $[ dependencies.CheckFileChanges.outputs['check(GET_ALL_PARAMETERS)'] ]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here.
In your test.template.yml

1. A [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#steps) sequence cannot have a `variables` section
2. The `each` keyword [can only be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword) on parameters of type object.
3. There is no 'split' function.

Also, your parameter name in your pipeline 'WEBSITE_LIST' doesn't match the name defined in your template 'MY_LIST'

If you have a finite list of outputs from your first job you *could* do something like the below but this will not be sustainable if the list grows.

pipeline:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: AutomateScriptContent
    displayName: 'Some new trick'
    jobs:
      - job: CheckFileChanges
        displayName: Prepare list
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            persistCredentials: true
          - bash: |
                #....Something..Something
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=value1;isOutput=true;]foo"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=value2;isOutput=true;]bar"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=value3;isOutput=true;]lorem"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=value4;isOutput=true;]ipsum"
            displayName: "Check"
            name: check
            
      - job: TestTemplate
        variables:
          v1: $[ dependencies.CheckFileChanges.outputs['check.value1'] ]
          v2: $[ dependencies.CheckFileChanges.outputs['check.value2'] ]
          v3: $[ dependencies.CheckFileChanges.outputs['check.value3'] ]
          v4: $[ dependencies.CheckFileChanges.outputs['check.value4'] ]
        displayName: "Do something with values passed from env variable"
        dependsOn: CheckFileChanges
        steps:
        - template: __templates__/test.template.yml
          parameters:
            MY_LIST: [$(v1), $(v2), $(v3), $(v4)]
```

template

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: MY_LIST
    type: object

steps:
  - ${{ each value in parameters.MY_LIST }}:
    - script: 'echo ${{ value }}'
      displayName: '${{value}}'
```

Edit: as you explain that you do not know the number of output values from your first job, this does not seem possible to achieve.
Variables are always strings and, while you could output a csv string variable from the first job, there is no function available to split this into an array for use as the parameter of your second job.

Comment: Hello @Killian! thank you for the answer. About $WEBSITE_LIST, i've forgot to rename it before publishing the post.
About the variables passed instead, what i wanted to do is to export an array of objects which i don't know the length (in your case, instead of pushing v1, v2, v3 and v4, i would like to push arrV(v1, v2, v3, v4) as an output and call from template parameters and variables of TestTemplate job the array that i've set as env variable in the bash task.
This will allow me to create a foreach script echo {{ value }} depending on the values calculated in the bash script.

Comment: @Rokam, Yes, that's what I suspected. And that's where your problem is.
- Variables are always strings so you cannot output a task variable of type Array.
- There is no 'split' function so you cannot create an array parameter for your template from a csv string variable.

Comment: +1 thank you @Killian, I will proceed with another way! I suggest you editing the answer so you can write down that it cannot be done from csv line.

Comment: a `split` function does exist now: `{{ split(parameters.MY_LIST, ',') }}` and this will return the list of strings. If you knew you needed only the first element, I'm pretty sure you can directly do `{{ split(parameters.MY_LIST, ',')[0] }}`